# Error in pig script while processing large file

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I am trying to split a large file (15GB) into multiple small files based on a key column inside the file.The same code works fine if i run it on few 1000s of rows.

My code is as below.

```
REGISTER /home/auto/ssachi/piggybank-0.16.0.jar;
input_dt = LOAD '/user/ssachi/sywr_sls_ln_ofr_dtl/sywr_sls_ln_ofr_dtl.txt-10' USING PigStorage(',');
STORE input_dt into '/user/rahire/sywr_sls_ln_ofr_dtl_split' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.MultiStorage('/user/rahire/sywr_sls_ln_ofr_dtl_split','4','gz',',');
```

Error is as below

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser - ERROR 6015: During execution, encountered a Hadoop error.
```

HadoopVersion  2.6.0-cdh5.8.2
PigVersion       0.12.0-cdh5.8.2

I tried setting the below parameters assuming it is a memory issue, but it did not help.

```
SET mapreduce.map.memory.mb 16000;
SET mapreduce.map.java.opts 14400;
```

With the above parameters set, i got the below error.

```
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1

org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exception from backed error: AttemptID:attempt_1486048646102_2613_m_000066_3 Info:Exception from container-launch.
```

Comment: Are you using YARN? How much memory does that have? I ran Pig over a 96 GB file a few days ago just fine

Comment: Yes, i am using YARN. <property>
    <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb</name>
    <value>1024</value>
  </property>

Comment: Okay, that looks fine. My point was that you should open the YARN web UI and inspect your MapReduce logs

Comment: Where can i find the link for the YARN web UI?

Comment: That entirely depends how you installed Hadoop. You have CDH version, so are you using Cloudera Quickstart VM?

Answer (score 0):

Whats the Cardinality of your " key column " is it in 1000?

If its in 1000 then you will get the error as your Mappers are dying because of OOME.

Do understand each Mapper now maintain 1000 file pointers and a associated buffer for each filePointer enough to occupy whole of your heap.

Can you please provide logs of your mappers for further investigation

Multioutput in MapReduce which is being called internally. 
http://bytepadding.com/big-data/map-reduce/multipleoutputs-in-map-reduce/